# Rendering PHP file w/out full Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, rendering

I am working on a project for a friend making some edits to a PHP landing page. They have sent me all assets for the single landing page. This includes associated PHP, JS, CSS, images, etc. But its just for that particular landing page template, not the entire site. The landing page PHP file has Wordpress dependencies. I'm planning to work on it on a local server.

Crazily enough I've never encountered this. I have always worked in WP with a full theme installed.

How can I render the provided landing page PHP and all its associated assets without it being part of a theme?

I've attached a photo of the bundle sent to me as it appears at its root.

[SCREENSHOT OF THE BUNDLE SENT TO ME AS IT APPEARS AT ITS ROOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uISgr.png)

Any guidance would be so apprecaited! Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? You can either rewrite the WordPress dependencies, or load WordPress dependencies with `require( $path-to-wordpress.'/wp-load.php' );`

Comment: My question is how do I render, in a browser, a PHP file that has WP dependencies without it being part of a WP theme. Not going to rewrite all the dependencies. Where would I place the 'require' function? In the et-0003.php file? Thanks for the response!

Comment: What does the `et-0003.php` file contain?

Comment: All of the HTML and PHP for rendering the landing page.

Comment: Then I'd include the `require` before any call to a WP dependency.

Comment: Still nada with that added. When I navigate to the et-0003.php page on my local server I get a server error (500). "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8888/etlandingpage/et-0003.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: I guess it's time to put your debugging skills to work to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the WordPress dependencies by including the `wp-load.php` script which will make everything available to your script.

```
require(WP_PATH."/wp-load.php");
```

WordPress still needs to be setup and configured with database connection by editing `wp-config.php`.